# OnPropertyChanged - Calculated property

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток. Такой вопрос:

имеется модель:

```
public class MyModel : ModelBase
{
    public double Count
    {
        get => _count;
        set
        {
            _count = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public virtual Model2 Model2
    {
        get => _model2;
        set
        {
            _model2 = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get => decimal.Round(Model2.Price * (decimal)Count, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }
}
```

в MyModel есть свойство `Count`, в Model2 есть свойство `Price`. В MyModel есть Calculated свойство `Amount`.

А теперь **вопрос**: как мне уведомить об изменении Amount, когда поменялось свойство `MyModel.Count` и `Model2.Price?`

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("Amount")`?

Comment: @Zufir, в случае с `Count` такое пройдет. А в случае с `Model2.Price`?

Comment: `Model2` как-то сообщает при изменении `Price`?

Comment: @Андрей, да, также как и `MyModel`: `OnPropertyChanged();`.
Но проблема в том, что у меня идет привязка к `List<MyModel>`. И когда изменяется объект в списке, нужно уведомить об этом.

Comment: Вам нужно в сеттере `Model2 Model2` подписаться на его событие `PropertyChanged` и вызвать `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Amount));`

Comment: @Андрей, спасибо большое. Все получилось.`Model2.PropertyChanged += delegate { OnPropertyChanged("Amount"); };`

Comment: @AresGod, только перед этим надо отписаться от предыдущего и проверять что изменилось именно свойство `Price`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При смене `Model2` подпишитесь на ее событие `PropertyChanged` и вызовите `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Amount));`:

```
public virtual Model2 Model2
{
    get => _model2;
    set
    {
        _model2.PropertyChanged -= Model2PropertyChanged;
        _model2 = value;
        _model2.PropertyChanged += Model2PropertyChanged;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void Model2PropertyChanged(...)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Model2.Price))
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Amount));
}
```

Не забудьте при подписке проверку `Model2` на `null`
Могут быть неточности по синтаксису - не проверял

Comment: Спасибо. Изменил под себя, все работает.